# out of stock products in flat tables

Tags: products, out-of-stock, flat-catalog, flat

while selecting the products from flat table. out of stock products are missing.

Is there any configurations that will populate the out of products also in flat table?

Where the flat tables can be used in Magento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Out of stock product by changing a setting.

For magento2,goto **Admin>Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options**. **Display Out of Stock Products**: Choose Yes to enable displaying out of stock products in the frontend.

After that, you need to indexing using the command line.

> But Displaying out of stock products not means showing of Disable.
>   Flat table does not include Disable product at it table.